# C# Removing a specific header

Tags: c#, httpclient, multipart

I am currently trying to reproduce the following POST request:
[image: need]

Now with my code I am getting this:
[image: have]

I assume the first key is being added by using 
`System.Net.Http.StringContent`
unfortunately I could not find another way to craft it.

I am currently using the .NET Core C#.
So my code is built using httpclient. To reproduce the problem in less ( but ugly code ) I quickly pasted some code together.

**What do I have to do to end up with the same post request as in the first picture?**

My code:

```
String lMultipartBoundary = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

MultipartFormDataContent lMultipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent(lMultipartBoundary);

string header = string.Format("--{0}", lMultipartBoundary);
string footer = string.Format("--{0}--", lMultipartBoundary);
StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();
contents.AppendLine(header);
contents.AppendLine(String.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"", "adult"));
contents.AppendLine();
contents.AppendLine("1");

contents.AppendLine(header);
contents.AppendLine(String.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"", "thumb_size_contaner"));
contents.AppendLine();
contents.AppendLine("1");

contents.AppendLine(header);
contents.AppendLine(String.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"", "simple_upload"));
contents.AppendLine();
contents.AppendLine("Upload");

contents.AppendLine(footer);
lMultipartContent.Add(new StringContent(contents.ToString()));

var lFileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"D:\_Dev\Resources\trainee_iconset_226_icons_by_emey87-d36v4yq\48 px  web icons\PNG\basketball.png");
ByteArrayContent fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\_Dev\Resources\trainee_iconset_226_icons_by_emey87-d36v4yq\48 px  web icons\PNG\basketball.png"));

fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
{
    Name = "\"uploaded\"",
    FileName = "\"" + lFileInfo.Name + "\""
};
fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/png");
lMultipartContent.Add(fileContent);

lMultipartContent.Headers.Add("Origin", "https://imgtaxi.com");
var result = await client.PostAsync("/upload.php", lMultipartContent);
var lresponseJson = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What do I have to do to end up with the same post request as in the first picture?

Comment: Can you get the source of that first post request and use that?  We have limited visibility here to your code/challenge.  Would you be better approaching this with "How to post a file using c#" or some such question?

Comment: The first post request is the request I do with Chrome. I am trying to replicate it in C# to automate an upload. The data is being sent, the problem is  ( I assume ) the additional content, so the serverside does not want to handle my request.